# DAX YTD View in PowerBi (From Quarterly Data)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having an issue with creating YTD views in PowerBI (In DAX), I understand the time intelligence functions but the data I am given is quarterly, not monthly or daily so there is no efficient way to link it to a calendar.

How would I take data given in YYYYQ# and create measures to measure QoQ, YoY, MTD etc functions (preferably using time intelligence functions)?

Comment: The simplest solution is to use YYYYQQ01 (the first day of the quarter) instead of YYYYQ# (the latter can be just an attribute in a calendar table). This way, you can use a regular calendar table in your model and take advantage of the built-in time intelligence functions. Otherwise, you will have to write your own functions (not impossible, but not a good use of your time).

Comment: Thank you for the help and sorry for a late reply (it was sent to my spam folder).

So for example I get sales data by 2019Q1,2019Q2,2019Q3,2019Q4 etc... turning those values into 20190101, 20190202, 20190303 and 20190404 would allow me to use time intelligence when worked back into a Calendar table?